# Why is UISearchBar not shown correctly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In order to understand how UISearchDisplayController works i've written the following code in viewDidLoad method:

```
UISearchBar * searchBar = [[[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 40.0f)] autorelease];
searchBar.delegate = self;
searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

_searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
_searchController.delegate = self;
_searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
_searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;

[_searchController setActive:YES animated:YES];
[_searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

But when i run my code the UISearchBar doesn't being shown as you can see in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create UISearchBarcontroller its good but not added in uiviewcontroller. So You add UISearchBarcontroller in uiviewcontroller.

coding:

[self.view addsubview:_searchController];